# All-DAy events, Timezones and Update

Tags: c#, timezone, exchangewebservices

```
        ItemId id=null;
        string s = "";
        const string dts = " dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm ";
        if(true) {
            TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
            ExchangeService ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010, tz);
            ews.AutodiscoverUrl("Alexander@contoso.com");
            Appointment app = new Appointment(ews);
            app.IsAllDayEvent = true;
            app.StartTimeZone = tz;
            app.EndTimeZone = tz;
            app.Start = DateTime.Now;
            app.End = DateTime.Now;
            app.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
            id = app.Id;
            Console.WriteLine(app.Start.ToString(dts));
        }
        if(true) {
            TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
            ExchangeService ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010, tz);
            ews.AutodiscoverUrl("Alexander@contoso.com");
            Appointment app = Appointment.Bind(ews,id);
            Console.WriteLine(app.Start.ToString(dts));

            app.IsAllDayEvent = true;
            app.StartTimeZone = tz;
            app.EndTimeZone = tz;
            app.Start = DateTime.Now;
            app.End = DateTime.Now;
            app.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
            Console.WriteLine(app.Start.ToString(dts));
        }
        if (true)
        {
            TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
            ExchangeService ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010, tz);
            ews.AutodiscoverUrl("Alexander@contoso.com");
            Appointment app = Appointment.Bind(ews, id);
            Console.WriteLine(app.Start.ToString(dts));
        }
```

The console output is:

```
 05.05.2014 18:17 
 05.05.2014 00:00 
 05.05.2014 18:17 
 05.05.2014 02:00
```

So creating a new All-day event works like a charm (which is better than what I had this morning).

But why is the last line `02:00`, and how do I have to rewrite my program to have 00:00 CEST stored as the all-day appointment start date?

Comment: Downvote without comment... nice!

Comment: Did you try not setting the StartTimeZone and EndTimeZone properties on the Appointment object?  As far as I remember you should not set those properties if you specify the timezone when creating the ExchangeService object.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't change anything at all. The combination `Save() -> IsAllDayEvent=true -> Update()` seems to be poisonous.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a developer, but looking into this issue for our (Java) developers. It looks like you have to get **all** the timezone**s** from the original appointment or you will run into this issue... of the references/ other stack overflow questions below, number 5 got it and that was the last one that *I* found :(

1. [You are at the same stage as the person asking this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910129/timezone-change-to-utc-while-updating-the-appointment)
2. [One step closer, the actual time is correct, but the meeting displays the wrong time zone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356896/updated-appointment-via-ews-shows-utc-instead-of-local-tz)
3. [This similar question without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405324/ews-update-changes-time-zone-to-utc)
4. [Answered for these versions but I can't see what it means: Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 1 (SP1) / Exchange Server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484397/incorrect-timezone-of-ews-invitation-on-updates)
5. [This one actually got it to work right.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399957/incorrect-time-zone-displayed-in-outlook-after-updating-a-calendar-event-through) referencing [this answer on the Microsoft fora](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d89b587d-7315-4d9b-bc3f-4f348cb8ef53/ews-calendar-recurrence-item-update-timezone-problem?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

If this helps someone, maybe the others can also finally be closed :)

Comment: Microsoft told me that setting `IsAllDayEvent=true` on an existing appointment does not work correctly in Echange 2010 and Exchange 2010 SP 1. Exchange 2010 SP2 fixes the problem (but only if you connect with ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2...).